# How can I call in Django template a coordinate of a list's element?

Tags: python, django

I created a class that has some attributes. One of them is a list that has coordinates as elements.

Here's the python code:

```
@attr.s
    class ProductMetadata:
        features: list = attr.ib()
        #some other attrs

standard = ProductMetadata(
    features=[(True ,"Up to 1000 DMs"), (False, "Ludicrous mode"), (False, "Premium Support")],
    # the other attrs
)
```

And, since I'd like to write a list where the customer can see whereas he can benefit from a feature given his package, here's the code somehow I'd like to write:

```
<ul>
  {% for feature in product.metadata.features %}
     <li> <i class="lni {% if the first coordinate of the element is True %}lni-checkmark active"{% else %} lni-close {% endif %}></i>{{ the second coordinate }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Here's the result I'd like to get (visually):
[image: Result]

Also, given that the class name is `ProductMetadata`, and that the `product.attr` works when I just use Stripe (without the class), is using `product.metadata.attr` correct?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
  {% for feature in product.metadata.features %}
     <li> <i class="lni {% if feature.1%}lni-checkmark active"{% else %} lni-close {% endif %}></i>{{ feature.2 }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

You can use it like this

Comment: Thanks! So, for now, I can't check if the code works because I can't figure out how can I add that class to the Stripe object(s). The `ProductMetadata` class is in the function of `views.py`. Now, I have also this code here: `return render(request, 'instagram_prices.html', {
        'products': Product.objects.all()` which gets back the page and the objects from Stripe. How can I add the class I created to it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Create a dictionary in your view function or method and then send that to the template.Use ```obj =ProductMetadata()``` and create the dictionary like ```context={}``` and add keys to that like ```context['metadata']=obj```and then send it in renderlike ```return render(request,'template_namr',context)```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you add this to the answer? I keep getting errors

Comment: Okay, I think I figured it out, but if I add to a dictionary the `'metadata' : obj`, how can I add all the objects? This will add only one object, and even if I added more, dictionaries don't allow duplicates.

Comment: Look, if you'd like, you can answer here: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66204531/python-how-to-call-all-objects-of-a-class-with-their-attributes-in-django)